# Reference someelse's google doc script library in my script

Tags: permissions, google-apps-script, shared-libraries, spreadsheet

I am a user of a google spreadsheet(not the owner) with Edit permission, and want to reference to a script library created by another user. I know that the library script key and that the library has versions available. But when try to reference it in the script editor > Resource > Manage Libraries, I am getting the following error.

```
 *You do not have access to library LIB, used by your script, or it has been deleted.*
```

I am actually an owner of the library script. Am I missing something to make the library available to other users? Missing somesteps???

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need to share your library to allow others (in this case the Owner of the spreadsheet) to use it. There are some steps outlined in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13113564/scriptdb-in-library-accessed-by-webapp) but the gist of it is - 1. Open the Library project in the script editor 2. Go to File -> Share

Comment: The problem was that I created a script project as 'Blank Project', which does not have 'Share' menu item under File. So I had to create another project as 'Script as Web App' and was able to share the project. Thanks.