# Share a library by using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To share spreadsheets and documents it is easy to write a script:

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    sheet.addViewer("email@gmail.com");
```

A libray ia a stand alone Google Apps Script file. Is there a comparable script to share such a file?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using DriveApp as follows.

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
file.addViewer("email@gmail.com");
```

If you want to share files as ANYONE, you can use the following sample.

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);
```

#### References :

- [Access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access)
- [Permission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission)

Comment: Thanks for helping me again! Interesting solution. Is it not needed for working of the functions in the library to add the library on the google drive of "email@gmail.com"? If this is true the account "email@gmail.com" does not see the library, that means a better protection of my scripts in the library. Than i am even more happy!

Comment: @user3887038 If you want to use the function of the script as a GAS library, the users who use the library is not required to copy the script on own Drive. After it shared the script, the user of "email@gmail.com" can use the function by installing the function to the script as a library. Reference is https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/libraries If I misunderstand your comment, I'm sorry.

Comment: Indeed my script is a GAS library. So to give anyone to that file I don't need to share the library anymore. I searched and found this reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741173/source-code-of-libraries-used-by-webapps-visible-to-everybody.

Comment: @user3887038 I'm sorry for not being helpful.

Comment: In contrary you were very helpfull, At first i tried var file = DriveApp.getFileById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
file.addViewer("email@gmail.comsetSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW);

Comment: That works well, but your solution was even better because the library is not vissible at all for customer email@gmail.com. At the and I don't need this script at all, by sharing my library direct tot anyone with a link., My library is on this way better protected. So again thank you very much.

Comment: @user3887038 Thank you for your additional information.